# validate an xpath expression in Java

Tags: java, validation, xpath

Given an user input string, how can I tell whether it is a 
valid Xpath expression or not in Java. Just curious, since I cannot 
find a way to do it using javax.xml.xpath library. Thanks.

Comment: You ought to accept answers to every question you ask... it makes people less likely to devote time and effort to help you out and is a little bit ungrateful too.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I assume you want to validate the syntax but not if the expression is valid within the context of a your xml or xml schema. You can use the [compile(..)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/XPath.html#compile%28java.lang.String%29) method and it will throw an exception if the xpath is incorrect w.r.t the syntax.

```
XPathFactory factory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath xpath = factory.newXPath();
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//book[author='Abc']/title/text()");
```

Comment: what if I want to "lint" the XPath. For example, "//book[ 'Abc' ]" will compile (and yield true). But all my tests use XPath and I need to test my tests, so how do I detect that it should have been "//book[ @author = 'Abc' ]"?

Answer (score 1):

Run the XPath against some example XML document (e.g. `<a/>`). In most cases it won't return anything, but what you care about is whether it will throw an exception.