# Verifying selenium xpath syntax

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, xpath

I am writing a method in java to do a wait for an xpath.  However, if the wait elapses I do not want to throw an error.  I want to return null (or the element if it does find it).  I can surround with try/catch and if I catch an exception that says something like "an EXPECTED element was not found" I can return null;  But I would like to verify the syntax of the xpath first.  For instance here is an invalid xpath: `"//span[contains(@id,'ThisWillNEverBeFound" for obvious reasons of no closing ' nor ]"`.

This is further complicated by the fact that we have methods already written that just return that message about an expected element not found, regardless of whether it is a valid syntax or not.  So I cannot tell if it is a bad xpath.

I could write the wait myself, but instead of just passing an xpath (like String xpath) which usually I will do, I sometimes want a list (String... xpaths).  We have a method I can't really see that will wait for any of a given list of xpaths but I am not sure how to write one myself.

So I guess I am asking either is there a way to verify selenium xpaths have a correct syntax, or a way to do a wait for any of several xpaths?  I can catch the errors and examine them to see which ones are ok and which should be thrown.

Comment: In my opinion you don't want to do this. You shouldn't be evaluating whether the XPath is valid during execution. Whoever passed in the XPath should have done that before it was ever passed. I would try to fetch the element and if it's not found write the XPath to the log. When you find the error in the log, you can see if the XPath is the problem and go back and fix it if it is.

Comment: I understand your concern but wouldn't it alert the user to the fact that the xpath was not valid?

Comment: I thought about it some more and change my mind... kinda. :) I added an answer with some options I would consider.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can try executing the xpath on the browser's console and verify the output. Of course, the webpage on which you wish to verify your xpath needs to be opened.  You can execute by using `$x()`.

`$x()` is XPath utility function. You can check the Chrome's command line reference [docs](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/commandline-api#xpath).

Usage:

```
$x("//span[contains(@id,'ThisWillNEverBeFound" for obvious reasons of no closing ' nor ]")
```

Comment: OK, let me look into that.  Thank you.

Comment: I have a lot of XPaths that work on the console but are not found by Selenium.

Answer (score 0):

On second thought, maybe this isn't as bad as I originally thought. In my mind you have a few options...

1. Try to find the element. If it can't be found, write the XPath to the log so that you can determine at a later point if the XPath was valid.
2. Try to find the element. If it can't be found, validate the XPath and if it fails validation, write a message to the logs that the XPath was invalid.
3. Validate the XPath. If it's not valid, write a message to the log that it was invalid. Otherwise, try to find the element.

I guess I would prefer #2. With #1 you have to validate the XPath on investigation manually and that just seems slow and unnecessary. With #3, your execution may be slowed due to validating *every single XPath* and that seems wasteful. With #2, you see if you can find the element *first* ... then if you can't find it, you validate the XPath and write a message to the log.

There's a simple method of validating XPath syntax in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7606825/validate-an-xpath-expression-in-java).